# Select row based on max value in column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get the output from the input using Microsoft SQL Server? (Basically select the row per ID where vote is max).

**Input**

```
ID        Label    Vote
-----------------------
79185673    2        3
79185673    0       17
79185724    4        5
79185724    1       13
79185724    0        2
79185900    1       17
79185900    2        1
79185900    4        2
79186190    3        3
79186190    2       17
```

**Output**

```
ID        Label    Vote
-----------------------
79185673    0       17
79185724    1       13
79185900    1       17
79186190    2       17
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **`ROW_NUMBER`** or **`DENSE_RANK`** function to give a rank per `ID` in the descending order of `Vote` column and then select the rows having rank 1.

I prefer **`DENSE_RANK`** function, because it will give same rank for the same `Vote` values.

**Query**

```
;with cte as(
    select [rank] = DENSE_RANK() over(
        partition by [ID]
        order by [Vote] desc
    ), *
    from [your_table_name]
)
select [ID], [Label], [Vote] from cte
where [rank] = 1;
```

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting answers rewards the contributor for their effort and helps others to find a working solution.